# How to replace a group of characters of a word in a text file using batch script?

Tags: batch-file

Edited   **
I have a text file called sample.txt which keeps updating. It contains various pathnames:

> C:/users/admin/abc
>   C:/users/admin/xyz
>   C:/users/admin/jkl
>   C:/users/admin/mno
>   ...
>   ...

I want to replace "admin" with "admin1" and save that file in sample1.txt
I tried to use this:

```
y = admin1  
FOR /F "tokens=* delims=/" %%x in (sample.txt) DO ^  
if %%x==admin (%%y > sample1.txt) else (%%x > sample1.txt)
```

My output should in sample1.txt:

> C:/users/admin1/abc
>   C:/users/admin1/xyz
>   C:/users/admin1/jkl
>   C:/users/admin1/mno

Comment: Accept an answer in this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Will this simple batch file do?

```bat
@(For /F "Delims=" %%A In ('Find /I "/admin/"^<"sample.txt"'
) Do @Set "_=%%A"&@Call Echo %%_:/admin/=/admin1/%%)>"sample1.txt"
```

**Edit** The following may be less susceptible to poison characters in `sample.txt`

```bat
@(For /F "Delims=" %%A In ('Find /I "/admin/"^<"sample.txt"'
) Do @Set "_=%%A"&Call Set/P "_=%%_:/admin/=/admin1/%%"<Nul&Echo()>"sample1.txt"
```

Comment: Hey I think it works perfectly, but i found a glitch when i try to put the file name as "C:/users/admin/a&c" ..it does not work for this. Can you tell me how i can correct

Comment: TBF, my suggestion is to never have any directory or file named using characters which could cause issues, and that is one of those! You could escape the ampersand, **`&`**, with a caret, **`^`**, but my recommendation is that all of the paths within `sample.txt` should be doublequoted, `"C:/users/admin/a&c"`. I have edited my post with an awkward looking workaround which may however suit your purpose better.

Answer (score 1):

you can do the following for bash

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

declare -a myarray
readarray myarray < file_pathname # Include newline.
readarray -t myarray < file_pathname # Exclude newline.
new_string=admin1

for s in ${myarray[@]}; do
  echo $s;
  echo ${s/admin/$new_string}
done
```

Comment: the text file keeps updating so, everytime the end value "/abc" ,"/xyz" , etc will keep updating. So i will not be able to use that

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. It does what you want replaces `admin` with `admin1`

Comment: yes it will work. but my text file keeps updating and has many such pathnames inside the text file.

Comment: My text file can be:
C:/users/admin/abc
C:/users/admin/xyz
C:/users/admin/jkl
C:/users/admin/mno
C:/users/admin/asd
C:/users/admin/asdasd
C:/users/admin/jasdasdkl
C:/users/admin/asasd

Comment: as long as it's separated by newlines it doesn't matter,

Comment: yes i agree, but i cannot add the paths to the code every time the text file gets updated.

Comment: then why not just `cat <file>` to array?

Comment: how to do that?

Comment: I just edited the answer, next time please make it clear that you need something like that. if it does the job then pick my answer.

Comment: Sorry about that. but will this create a new text file sample1.txt?
and what should i put at the file_pathname?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155843/discussion-between-mike-tung-and-vaibhav-borkar).